# Python - BeautifulSoup - sorting out <td> on basis of data-title

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

Basically - how can I sort out all td:s with the data-title = "Senast", using BeautifulSoap?

I am laborating with the findall-function, using more arguments without success, for instance:

```
soup.findAll('td', {'class' : 'c02380 c02388 borderBottom c02373 c02386 c02382" data- title=\"Senast\"'}):
```

CODE:

```
 #! /usr/bin/python3
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                       
 from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

 url = "https://www....."

 soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())

 for item in soup.findAll('td'):
 print(item.prettify())
```

OUTPUT:

```
1.4
<!-- -->
<!-- -->
  SEK
</span>
<span aria-hidden="true">
1,40
</span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="addon addon--right">
<!-- -->
SEK
</span>
</span>
</td>

<td class="c02380 c02388 borderBottom c02373 c02386 c02382" data-title="Senast"  style="width:undefined;flex-basis:27%;order:3" theme="[object Object]">
<span class="number c02398" style="white-space:nowrap">
<span class="c02420">
<!-- -->
38.4
<!-- -->
</span>
<span aria-hidden="true">
 38,40
 </span>
 </span>
</td>

<td class="c02380 c02383 c02388 c02381 borderBottom c02386 c02382" data-title="Köp" style="width:undefined;flex-basis:NaN%;order:undefined" theme="[object Object]">
38,40
</td>

<td class="c02380 c02383 c02388 c02381 borderBottom c02386 c02382" data-title="Sälj" style="width:undefined;flex-basis:NaN%;order:undefined" theme="[object Object]">
38,40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `[attribute="value"]` CSS Selector:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select('td[data-title="Senast"]'):
    print(tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Output:

```
38.4
38,40
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to loop all the td:s and extract all the "Senast"-values, I only get two values as you get in the output. How can I loop all?

Comment: @java I Edited the answer